# Finding an explicit formula for the following exponential generating function

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

So I have the following formula for the coefficient of the recursion and I am trying to find an explicit formula for $a_n$ the nth coefficient:

$$ a_n = (n+1)a_{n-1} + 3^n $$ 
$$ a_0 = 1; \space\space\space n\geq1  $$

Here's what I have done so far (I may be incorrect in some intermediate steps, I am not sure):

expand the $(n+1)$ term so that we have $ a_n = na_{n-1} + a_{n-1}+ 3^n $, multiply all sides by $ \frac{x^n}{n!}$ and sum over $ n $ giving the following:

$$\sum_{n \geq1}{a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}} = \sum_{n \geq1}n a_{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n \geq1} a_{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n \geq1}3^n\frac{x^n}{n!} $$

Let's call the exponential generating function $\sum_{n \geq0}{a_n\frac{x^n}{n!}} = G(X)$
$$ \therefore G(x) = xG(x) + xe^x + 3^ne^x - 3^n +1 $$

and this simplifies to:
$$ G(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}e^x + \frac{3^n}{1-x}e^x + \frac{3^n}{1-x} + \frac{1}{1-x}$$

I am quite stuck here, for the first term on the RHS I have: $\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{i!}$ for the second term I have $3^n\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{i!} $ for the third term I have $3^n  \sum_{n\geq0} x^n$ and for the final term I have $\sum_{n\geq0} x^n$ (so taking the coefficients of the x terms we get:

$$a_n = \sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{i!} + 3^n\sum_{i = 0}^{n-1} \frac{n!}{i!} + 3^n + 1$$

which gives the wrong answer... can anyone help me out see where I went wrong?

Thank you!

edit: I realize there is a post asking the same question which uses integration/differentiation; I am trying to do this without the use of calculus.

Comment: When you write $$\therefore G(x) = xG(x) + xe^x + 3^ne^x - 3^n +1$$ what is $n$?

Comment: n corresponds to the number of the nth coefficient of $x^n$ i.e: $n = 3$ is when we're looking for the third coefficient of the recurrence

Comment: Suspiciously similar to a recent question, where did you get the problem from?

Comment: Why would $n=3$?

Comment: It is the same question, the solution discussed involves the use of cauchy products and calculus which is not how I am attempting this problem; I am wondering if there is another way to do it. See my edit. It's just an example in response to the first comment.

Comment: My comments from the linked duplicate discuss the same exact issue. Again, what exactly is $n$? Is it $3$?

Comment: @skidjoe I am pretty sure you missed the point of my question.  The $n$ only makes sense inside the summation, so bringing the $3^n$ outside is nonsense.  In other words, something like $$\sum_{n\geq 0} 3^n x^n = 3^n \sum_{n\geq 0} x^n$$ makes no sense, as the expression on the right has a free "n" while the expression on the left has no free "n"

Answer (score 1):

You've got the limits wrong. That's why I always insist in *no subtraction in indices*.

Write:

$\begin{align*}
  a_{n + 1}
   &= (n + 2) a_n + 3 \cdot 3^n \\
  \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} \frac{z^n}{n!}
   &= \sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 2) a_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
        + 3 \sum_{n \ge 0} 3^n \cdot \frac{z}{n!} \\
   &= z \sum_{n \ge 1} a_n \frac{z^{n - 1}}{(n - 1)!}
        + 2 \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n \frac{z^n}{n!}
        + 3 e^{3 z} \\
  G'(z)
   &= z G'(z) + 2 G(z) + 3 e^{3 z}
\end{align*}$

From the initial value $a_0 = 1$ you get the initial value $G(0) = 1$. The solution is:

$\begin{align*}
   G(z)
     &= \frac{(3 z - 6) e^z + 5}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align*}$

The fun of extracting coefficients I leave to the gentle reader.

Comment: Your solution gives $G(0)=-1$. I get $G(x)=\frac{(4-3x)e^{3x}-1}{3(1-x)^2}$.